# How to compile python with cython and avoid import limits on Windows?

Tags: python, python-3.x, cython, cythonize

#### Env:

Windows10
python==3.6.6
cython==0.29.14

#### Description:

There is [issue](https://github.com/cython/cython/issues/3211) in cython repo. + I've created example [reporitory](https://github.com/Yuriy-Leonov/cython_imports_limit_issue) with steps for reproducing this issue.

After compiling project with `cython`, following exception -> `ImportError: DLL load failed: Произошел сбой в программе инициализации библиотеки динамической компоновки (DLL).` (English version: `ImportError: DLL load failed: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.`) is raised when try to run compiled application.

As was figured out it happens after reaching some count of imports in project (no matter: these imports are in one file or in several files).

#### Question:

Maybe someone faced with this problem and know how to fix that? (suggest to use less import is not an option)

**PS:** This issue is reproduced only on Windows and not reproduced on Ubuntu 18.04. (MacOS wan't tested)
If more details are required - I would be glad to provide it (if you expain how to get such details)

Comment: This looks a lot like a Windows limit about the number of DLLs a process can load. If so, it probably won't be fixable by either the Python or Cython maintainers.

Comment: The associated Python bug report is https://bugs.python.org/issue38597 - it doesn't have a resolution, but I suspect this is the better place to report the bug than Cython

Comment: @DavidW thank you for such information